# How to sleep() inside of grape API in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, grape-api

While js/front-end development i need to put some sleep inside of my api endpoint because now they are almost instant.

I've tried to:

```
module Api
  class Base < Grape::API

    sleep 2

    mount Api::V1::Base

  end
end
```

and:

```
module Api
  class Base < Grape::API

    mount Api::V1::Base

    def initialize
        sleep 2
        super()
    end

  end
end
```

But in both cases it works only the first time (first time after some change introduced in code, to be precise). Every next is instant.

I could of course put `sleep 2` inside every resource `get()` method, but i would rather not end up putting it all over the code.

How can i do that?

Comment: Can you tell us why it's bad that your API is too quick? Something feels very very wrong about this.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom no, there's nothing wrong with that, but i'm doing it the `reactive components` way, so the page loads without any data, fires up it's components and components fetches their data via ajax calls. So they should show some loading indicators and stuff like that, but now whole page load + ajax calls lasts about 200ms so i can't polish that sort of things.

Comment: I wonder if you could accomplish the same thing using Chrome's web dev "network throttling" features?